# Is it possible to get mouse inputs from JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

Good day! I have experimenting with Swing and AWT, and I stumbled upon java.swing.JFrame and java.awt.event.MouseListener.

Based on the following code:

**Game.java**

```
    (...)

    public Game() {
    frame = new JFrame();

    ih = new IH();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    (...)
    frame.add(this);
    frame.addMouseListener(ih);
}
```

**IH.java**

```
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    public class IH implements MouseListener {

       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {    
            System.out.println(e.getX());
            System.out.println(e.getY());
            System.out.println("Got clicked");
       }

       public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    }
       public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {    }
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    }

    }
```

I haven't received any output from the Console, though I didn't receive any errors either. I am expecting to receive x and y coordinates on where I am clicking on in the JFrame. How can I do this? Or, is it not possible to this within a JFrame? What should I use then?

Comment: Given `frame.add(this);`, try `this.addMouseListener(ih);`.  But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it locally and it works as intended. What do you add with `frame.add(this)` ?

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame t = new JFrame();
    t.setSize(500, 500);
    t.addMouseListener(new IH());
    t.show();
}

public static class IH implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getX());
        System.out.println(e.getY());

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You do know that t.show( ) is deprecated. You should use t.setVisible(true) instead...Thanks anyways. Your code works!